# Purpose of using ? super T or T super SomeClass in generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of using `<? super T>` in generics in Java. I have read a lot, but haven't understood it yet. It is clearly for me using `<T extends SomeClass>`, if the class is SomeClass or subclass of SomeClass we don't need to now exact type of subclass, we know only that it has methods of superclass `SomeClass`, so we can invoke methods like `T.someMethod();` It is very powerful feature. But I cannot understand purpose of using `<T super SomeClass>`.

What privileges we have writing such wildcard? T is super class of SomeClass, so what Super class may doesn't have methods of SomeClass, we can only ensure that super class of SomeClass has all methods of Object so this becomes useless, so what is the purpose of using this?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 2):

You can express Lower Bound wildcard using `? super T`. Let say that you want to develop a method that can put Double into a list .

```
public void foo(List<Double> d) {}
```

But if you can declare this method like

```
public void foo(List<? super Double> d) {}
```

Then you can pass `List<Double>`, `List<Number>, and List<Object>` . Hence you achieved more flexibility and re-usability. Also other way to look at `? super T` is via **PUT principle**

> use a super wildcard when you only put values into a structure.

Comment: Thx for answer but List<String> and List<Object> are not compatible. I cannot put Object in List<String> .

Comment: Obviously that's why i mentioned "That you can pass" , i didn't mentioned that you can put